# How do you say you're speaking on behalf of a group of people?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have an English assignment where I have to speak on behalf of a marginalised group, I've chosen dyslexia, as my brother is dyslexic, but I'm not sure how to exactly put it into persuasive words. Can anyone help me please? Thanks a million.

Comment: You are _representing_ that group.

Comment: You are *advocating* for that group.

Comment: You are _defending_ that group.

Comment: Have you been authorised to speak for the group?

Comment: You can also say that you are attempting to *give voice* to that group.

Comment: Your own phrase, *on behalf of*, works.

Comment: You speak _for_ that group. We would understand that your thoughts champion the whole group.

Answer (score 1):

try the word ["advocate"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/advocate):

> n. A person who supports others to make their voices heard, or ideally
>   for them to speak up for themselves.

In your case, you can say that you're an **"advocate for dyslexics"**